# What's the best way to add rows to the table if the table has pagination?

Tags: tables, pagination

I am designing a table where the data in the table is added manually by the user. There's an 'add data' button below the table, using which an empty row gets created and the user can feed in their data. Now the problem is that the number of rows in this table could run in the hundreds. Thus we need to have a pagination where up to 50 records will be shown on each page and beyond that, users need to click 'next' in the pagination to view more data. In this case, if the table has 50 records in all and the user clicks on 'Add Data', where should the new row be added - on the current page (page 01) or on the next page?

[image: screenshot of the image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are adding the new row to the page and I assume you can't guarantee that this item always shows up on the same page. When you refresh this page/table, the row could possibly disappear from this page.

Instead it should be added to the whole set of data, so I suggest to use a modal to add a new item. When the item is saved and the modal closes, refresh the page/table and show a message above the table mentioning that item has been created with a link to it. The link navigates to the page in the table where the new item is. A sortable column for the creation date and a search field are also welcome additions to the table since earlier created items should also be easy to find.